# How can I add JQuery commands in cssLess?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I'm using CSSLess and JQuery and am trying to count the number of LI elements in an unordered list so I can divide that number for the width.

```
ul.navBar {
    li {
        float: left;
        width: (100% / `$(".navBar li").length()`);
    }
}
```

The output should appear as tabs side by side like a standard nav bar menu.

Is there a way to write this without JQuery?

Comment: I'm a little bit suspicious of this code...are you using box-sizing: content-box? Barring that, is there no padding, border, or margin on these li elements?

Comment: Your title asks how to use jQuery, and then you ask how to do it without jQuery.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
li { 
    float: left; 
    width: ~`(100/$('.navBar li').length)+'%'`;
}
```

The `~` tells `less` that you don't want it to mess with the output.

You could also use `percentage`:

```
width: percentage(`1/$('.navBar li').length`);
```

This only works if you don't have borders, padding, etc that would make your `li` elements any wider.  Also, you must load this at the **bottom** of your `body`, otherwise the jQuery will run before your DOM is ready:

```
<body>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="mystyles.less"> 
  <script src="less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

</body>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ZJ2HV/

Comment: The percentage solution is perfect. Wow, thank you for the fast response and answer!